# Plotting PolyLine on Google Map not working Android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-play-services

I am trying to plot a polyline on my Android map. I have read the other stack overflow answers and they are not correcting my issue. I have definitely added google play services to my app as a dependency.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mattboyle.windowrunner"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
//apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

//afterEvaluate {
//    tasks.findByName("assembleDebug").dependsOn("testDebugClasses")
//}

dependencies {
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.telly:groundy:1.5'
    compile 'com.telly:groundy-compiler:1.5'



}
```

This is my very simple code to do it:

```
System.out.println("About to add to polyoptions");
        PolylineOptions routeOption = new PolylineOptions().addAll(RunningMap.routeToPlot);
    System.out.println("Added them all and routeoptions is of size "+routeOption.getPoints().size());
    Polyline polyline = map.addPolyline(routeOption);
    System.out.println("Should have plotted now..");
```

It hits all the System outs.

PolylineOptions.size() returns 102 and there doesn't seem to be any other errors.

The Map is initialised properly and I can see it on my android screen.

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

This seems like it should work and I can't understand why it isn't. I really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

In Google's official documentation for [PolyLine Options](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions.html), There is no method like size(). This might be the probable cause of the error you are getting. Please refer to the document to know about the supported methods.

Hope this would help!!